# Mongo class not found in Heroku PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, heroku, mongohq

I am using Heroku PHP, and has added the MongoHQ addon.

But it gives an error "class Mongo not found" at the line `$m = new Mongo();`

What else do I need to setup mongo driver on Heroku?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now supported.

Follow the instructions at https://gist.github.com/1288447

Custom extensions can be added to `/app/www/ext/` with your custom `php.ini`!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku currently does not support Mongo PHP classes.

Yeah, you can add the MongoHQ add-on etc, but Mongo driver is still not available for PHP yet. This answer comes for Heroku support.